# Pass a list of selected object IDs through to controller when form is submitted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Not terribly experienced in Rails and looking for a sanity check - I have a form for users to create a list. On this form, I will (eventually) have a search field where they can search for existing objects to add to their list. There will be over 50,000 items, so listing them all at once is not an option. Since this aspect is complex, something like Cocoon didn't seem flexible enough for me and I opted to go about building the association between list and items myself in the controller or models.

The desired workflow is -

1. User finds item and clicks on a "Add" link
2. Item then displays in a staging area on the page showing the pending items to be added.
3. User adds any other desired items and submits the form
4. item IDs are passed to the controller where I build the associations between the created list and selected items.

My current solution is to store item ID's in a hidden field for the form and pass them to the controller that way. It seems I will have to disable Turbolinks to get this method to work since it keeps reloading the page and thus overwriting my hidden field to the default values when I click one of the "add item" links.

Is there a cleaner way to do this I'm missing?

Comment: To get the help you're looking for, please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information, but I assume you are using a `anchor` tag?

You need to disable the defaults on the `anchor` tag so you don't get a refresh, etc, eg:

```
<a class="s-inte" />
$('.s-inte').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})
```